# Anyone know tools/plugin/script to convert build.gradle groovy to kts easily?

Tags: android, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Android Studio Giraffe was released and the recommended build configuration language is now Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts) and not Groovy DSL (build.gradle). I want to update my existing project from Groovy to KTS. I know the [step-by-step migration guide](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl). But, is there any tool to convert it easily? Such as some scripts or plugins?

I just found https://gradle-kotlinize.web.app/ but it does not convert properly.

[image: Screenshot]

There is no parenthesis at implementation conversion and it will result in an error if we add `compileOptions` code.

Any suggestion is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found that the terminal version working well.
You can follow the tutorial at https://github.com/bernaferrari/GradleKotlinConverter.

But if you have other tools, especially using GUI. Please answer below.